# On Windows 10, My MAMP is greyed out and Won't Start Servers, Trying to Run Apache Servers

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

My Mamp is not working whatsoever. I am trying to run PHP 5.6.0 on it (which seems like the cause for it to not work?). I am using that php file because it is required for the project I am working on. I've looked up solutions and I have already tried the renaming of the mysql-bin.* files. I don't what to do or why MAMP isn't working. Everything is greyed out and the servers won't start.

[image of my mamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1tvk.png)

[picture of my php error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQihr.png)

Comment: 1) Look at the error logs. 2) If they are no help Look at the Window Event Viewer for messages from `MYSQL` and/or `Apache`.

Comment: It may be that you need to check you have installed ALL the relevant MSVC Runtime libraries. Simple process is to install ALL of them from VC2008 to VC2019

Comment: I looked in the error logs and don't understand what they mean. I updated/edited my post with a pic of my error log from Ok, I will install the MSVC Runtime libraries? How do I know which ones I need?

Comment: Then show them to us, :)